# Kotlin - switching object detail based on group by

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion

For example I have a class with below json format

```
[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "detail": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "detail": [
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
]
```

how to change grouped it based on the detail?

```
[
    {
        "detail": "1",
        "name": [
            "a"
        ]
    },
    {
        "detail": "2",
        "name": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    },
    {
        "detail": "3",
        "name": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    },
    {
        "detail": "4",
        "name": [
            "b"
        ]
    }
]
```

below is my class structure

```
data class funName(
    @field:JsonProperty("name")
    val name: String = "",

    @field:JsonProperty("detail")
    val detail: Array<String> = arrayOf(""),

)
```

and my object is based on the array of `funName`

```
val data: Array<funName> = ...
```

i really have no idea how to do it.

```
val convert = data.groupBy { x -> x.detail  } ??
```

Is this doable in kotlin/java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the original data is grouped by `name`, you can think of the original data as a list of pairs

```
name detail
a    1
a    2
a    3
b    2
b    3
b    4
```

Mapping it to this format first would make it very easy to group by the second thing (detail) in the pair.

Since each `funName` corresponds to multiple pairs like this, you should use `flatMap` on `data`.

```
val result = data.flatMap { funName -> 
        funName.detail.map { funName.name to it } 
    }
    .groupBy(keySelector = { (name, detail) -> detail }, valueTransform = { (name, detail) -> name })
    // or more concisely, but less readable
    // .groupBy({ it.second }) { it.first }
```

This will get you a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

If you want a `List<Result>`, where `Result` is something like

```
data class Result(
    val detail: String = "",
    val names: List<String> = listOf(),
)
```

You can add an additional `map`:

```
.map { (k, v) -> Result(k, v) }
```

Comment: thank you for teaching me of `keySelector` and `valueTransform` inside of `groupBy`. I have tested it, and it works well